# При изменении масштаба страницы расползается меню

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

В верстке меню

```
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li class="about_us" ><a href="javascript:void(0)">About Us</a></li>
   <li class="services"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Services</a></li>
   <li class="partners"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Partners</a></li>
   <li class="contact_us"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

стили

```
nav {
    margin: 45px 0 0 22px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/icon_menu.png) center top no-repeat ; 
}

.services {
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
}

.partners {
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
}

.contact_us {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #235f79;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'freesetcregular';
}
```

вот так выглядит меню при масштабе в 100% (масштабе по умолчанию)
[image: http://i.imgur.com/hmqQq.png]

при изменении масштаба страницы пункты меню начинают то уезжать в разные стороны, например, при масштаба 150% меню выглядит так
[image]

как можно добиться того, чтобы меню не разъезжалось при масштабировании?
вся верстка выложена [здесь](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index7/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пункты меню расположены на фоне изображения, потому фиксировать каждый пункт меню **width**-ом.

```
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/icon_menu.png) center top no-repeat; 
    width: 60px;
}

.services {
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
}

.partners {

}

.contact_us {

}
```

Comment: да, большое спасибо, получилось